# Unexpected Error ASP.net repeater FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using the following `ItemDataBound` to calculate values for my page fields but I am getting and `Unexpected Error`:

C#:

```
protected void rptLicenseHistory_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txLicenseHistoryType")).Text = "Test";

}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptLicHistory" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rptLicenseHistory_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="display:flex;width: 100%;align-items: center;">
            <div style="width:60px;">License:</div>
            <div style="width:170px;"><asp:TextBox ID="txLicenseHistoryType" runat="server"/></div>
        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>                    
     <SeparatorTemplate>
        <div style="height: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
     </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`Textbox ID "txLicenseHistoryType"` Should return "Test" but I get an `Unexpected Error`.  Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the wrong control event. Most controls (even a plain text box) has a databind event.

You want to deal with EACH row, and thus you want to use the data "item" event.

In most cases for GridView, ListView and others, it usually called "row data bind" something or other.

In the case of a repeater, we want that even FOR EACH ITEM, and thus the markup should be this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptLicHistory" runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="rptLicHistory_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; align-items: center;">
            <div style="width: 60px;">License:</div>
            <div style="width: 170px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txLicenseHistoryType" runat="server" /></div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <div style="height: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Note the use of OnItemDataBound - for "each" item it means to help you remember.

So, now your code behind would be this:

```
protected void rptLicHistory_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
        (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        Debug.Print($"Working on row = {e.Item.ItemIndex}");
        ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txLicenseHistoryType")).Text = "Test";
    }
}
```

Note how you have to test if this is a "item" or a "alternate row" item. The reason is that you have heading rows, and other types of template rows, so you have to in code make sure you ONLY are grabbing + dealing with the row, or alternating row.

The above when run should look like this:

[image]

## Edit: Get full data row for each row binding

So, say in place of "hard coded" assignment of "test"?

We could do this:

```
    protected void rptLicHistory_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DataRowView MyDataRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txLicenseHistoryType")).Text = MyDataRow["HotelName"].ToString();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: OK, this works perfectly with the `Test` literal.  Assigning `((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txlicenseHistoryType")).Text = e.Item.DataItem.Type`, however, causes an error `object does not contain a definition for Type`.  I'm almost there!

Comment: Hum, you lost me. Our example was hard coded to assign "Test". If you want use of the full data row used for the binding event, then see my edit above. I'm binding the repeater to a datatable, but you can/could use the object type (of one type, not a list<of type> to get the one row object used to bind that one row.

Comment: I got it!  Thanks for all your help, Albert!  Brilliant!

Comment: Also, my bad, you have to use type DataRowView. In desktop land, .DataItem is actually the object type, but it looks like in web land, the "object list type of whatever" is casted to a DataRowView, but that's ok anyway. but, my suggesting that you can get/grab a single row of the object type used to data bind is wrong.

Comment: I was able to grab it according the the row data type....not a problem.  You showed me the backbone of the concept and it is much appreciated.